# Prevent 3rd party extension from sending messages to my extension / add filter to runtime.onConnectExternal and runtime.onMessageExternal

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have 2 extensions that must communicate with each other over runtime.sendMessage /  runtime.connect. However, I worry that this exposes a gateway for foreign extensions to try to communicate with our own. I know I can just check for the sender inside the event handlers. Nonetheless, I still fear that if another extension starts spamming my own it may create havoc. I would rather find a way to completely ban an extension that behaves this way from communicating with ours.

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve this?

Comment: For that reason you have `externally_connectable` in the manifest file, where you filter which extensions can connect with yours. [Link to documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/externally_connectable/)

Comment: That's golden. Thanks a lot. Would you know if it is possible to dynamically modify this?

Comment: You cannot modify the manifest file dynamically, but you can, as you already mentioned, check the sender inside the event handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would +1, but It doesn't seem I have that privilege yet.